# Haskell fromIntegral -- type confusion

Tags: haskell, type-conversion

I am just going through "Real World Haskell" and I am doing the excercises that come along with it.

And i noticed something that i think is odd.

Take this function for example:

`myAverage :: (Fractional a) => [a] -> Maybe a
myAverage [] = Nothing
myAverage xs = Just $ (mySum xs) / (fromIntegral $  myLength xs)`

The `(/)` function wants two arguments that are instances of `Fractional`.
`myLength` returns an `Int` so i use `the fromIntegral` function as i have been told.

But `fromIntegral` only garantees that the returned value will be an instance of `Num`.

Why does `Num` also "include" an instance of `Fractional` in this case. Isn't `Fractional` more specific?

Why doesn't the compiler complain that i have just a `Num` from the return type and not a "proper" `Fractional`.

Why can't i use the `Int` directly, it is also an instance of `Num`, is it not?

In the case of calling `mySum` i get it. It takes a list of `Num`s but i feed it with a list of `Fractional`s (which are also `Num`s, because they are derived from it). The return type has the same type, which is evident from the type annotation (see below): a single element of `Fractional`

But in case of `fromIntegral` i cannot infer myself (the compiler obviously can :-)) that the returned value is also an instance of `Fractional`. Why?
The type it takes is clearly no `Fractional`.

The whole function works as expected.

Just for clarification:

`mySum :: (Num a) => [a] -> a
myLength :: [a] -> Int`

Thank you,

Lazarus

Comment: What is your `mySum` and `myLength`? Ok - I see them now.

Comment: `mySum` just adds up all the numbers in a list. `myLength` counts the elements in a list.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`fromIntegral` doesn't produce some unknown type of which we only know that it's an instance of `Num`. `fromIntegral` produces whichever type we (usually implicitly) ask it to, as long as its an instance of `Num`.

In terms of OO languages, you need to think of it as generics/templates, not virtual inheritance/subtype polymorphism. That is the equivalent Java signature for `fromIntegral` would look like `<A extends Integral, B extends Num> B fromIntegral(A i)`, not `Num fromIntegral(Integral i)`.

so if we want an `Int`, we get an `Int`. If we want an `Integer`, we get an `Integer`. And if we want a `Double`, we get a `Double`. But if we want a `String`, we're out of luck as `String` is not an instance of `Num`.

In this case we want an `a` where `a` is the element type of the given list. So if we pass in a list of `Double`s, `fromIntegral` gives us a `Double` and if we pass in a list of `Rational`s, `fromIntegral` gives us a `Rational`.

Comment: Nice thanks. Also the analogy with Java very nice. Being more of a C++ guy myself i would implement such a function with template specialization. So there is one generic version and a specialisation for each concrete type, which actually does the correct conversion. Does haskell implement this? Do you know by any chance?

Comment: @Lazarus535 `fromIntegral` has exactly one definition, which is `fromIntegral = fromInteger . toInteger`. `fromInteger` is part of the `Num` typeclass, so it's defined separately for each `Num` type, and `toInteger` is part of the `Integral` typeclass, so again it's defined separately for each integral type.

Comment: Yeah. Thats it. If the functions that the `fromIntegral` is composed of are all part of their respective typeclasses than it is basically like template specialisation in C++. THX.

Comment: @Lazarus535 Not quite. `fromIntegral` is just a plain non-specialized template function, whereas `fromInteger` and `toInteger` aren't templates at all. They're just overloaded for each instance of `Num` and `Integral` respectively. Here's a sketch of how you'd implement similar behavior in C++: http://codepad.org/qCt0tte8

Comment: Thanks for putting together this nice sample :-). Template specialisations would be a bit of an overkill here...and would not provide more type safety. You still could pass a Double instead of an intended Int (for example) to the fromIntegral function and the C++ compiler would (almost) silently eat it.

Comment: @Lazarus535 Yes, because there's an implicit conversion from double to int. If we replace the typedefs at the beginning with wrapper classes (and don't define any implicit conversions for them), we do get the same type safety as in Haskell. Except that in Haskell the type signature explicitly states which typeclasses the given types need to instance, whereas in C++ the required overloads are not visible in the signature. You can only tell by going through the code or reading the documentation (if it existed)  - something which concepts would have fixed, had they made it into the language.

Comment: Additionally one could add explicit constructors in the wrapper classes that create objects just from the indented values. Together with just one type cast operator, one could even call the `fromIntegral` with the original types and still be type-safe (wrapper classes as template argumens still). And then you have finally hit the 10x code size difference between Haskell and C++ ;-)

Answer (score 6):

You ask:

> But fromIntegral only garantees that the returned value will be an instance of Num.

That's true, but consider the type of `fromIntegral`:

```
fromIntegral :: (Integral a, Num b) => a -> b
```

So `fromIntegral` allows us to convert an `Int`, for example, to *any* other Num instance.

For the time being, let's deal with concrete types instead of type classes. Suppose you had defined `myAverage` like this:

```
myAverage :: [Double] -> Maybe Double
myAverage [] = Nothing
myAverage xs = Just $ mySum xs / (fromIntegral (myLength xs))
```

`Double` supports division, and `fromIntegral` is able to convert the `Int` returned from `myLength` to a `Double`.

The same definition would work if you used `Rational` instead of `Double`, e.g.:

```
myAverage :: [Rational] -> Maybe Rational
```

Back to type classes and how it type checks:

```
myAverage :: Fractional a => [a] -> Maybe a
...
myAverage xs = Just $ mySum xs / (fromIntegral (myLength xs))
```

Here's how it goes:

1. `a` is Fractional, and Fractional is a subclass of Num, so `a` is also a Num.
2. `xs` has type `[a]`, so `mySum xs` has type `a`
3. `myLength xs` has type `Int`
4. `fromIntegral` can convert `Int` into any other Num instance, so it can convert an `Int` into an `a`
5. `mySum xs` and the fromIntegral expression both have type `a` which is a Fractional, so we can perform the division.

Comment: Thanks for answering. The thing that had me confused was that in Haskell type deduction works in "both directions".