# Haskell - The type signature lacks an accompanying binding

Tags: haskell

**My task:** Define a function that replicates a given word n times

```
repliNow :: Integer -> String -> String
```

Which gives me

> beginner.hs:1:1: error:
>       The type signature for ‘repliNow’ lacks an accompanying binding
>     |
>   1 | repliNow :: Integer -> String -> String
>     | ^^^^^^^^

How do I solve this?

Comment: Um, by implementing the function, as demanded by the task‽ (If you want to implement it later but first complete other stuff in the module, you can for the time being make it `undefined`.)

Comment: Well as the error says, you did not provide an *implementation*, only a *signature*.

Comment: Sorry, Im a complete noob. Can you give me an example of an implementation?
Like: repliNow :: n
?

Comment: An implementation is one or more `=` clauses. I.e. `repliNow = undefined` or `repliNow n str = "Sorry, today I don't feel like replicating the word "++str++" "++show n++" times."`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I understand what you're getting at... I often read the :: symbol as "is defined as" which is a good way to read the function. So yes, you correctly DEFINED the function. repliNow :: Integer -> String -> String could be read as: "repliNow IS DEFINED AS a function that takes an Integer and a String as input and then outputs a String". But if you just put that into a haskell source code file and try to run it then GHC will complain because, as the other answer stated, you have merely given a signature not an implementation. So you've already fought half the battle with the signature definition and for an implementation there are many paths to success, for instance using recursion:

```
repliNow :: Integer -> String -> String
repliNow 0 _   = ""
repliNow n str = str ++ repliNow (n-1) str
```

Or perhaps ya wanna get fancy wif functions:

```
repliNow :: Integer -> String -> String
repliNow n str = concat $ replicate (fromIntegral n) str
```

I would recommend checking out these resources to further your Haskell know-how:

[replicate and concat](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch20.html#x28-23300020.4),
[recursion](http://learnyouahaskell.com/recursion#hello-recursion),
[lists](http://learnyouahaskell.com/starting-out#an-intro-to-lists),
[fromIntegral](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31855909/haskell-fromintegral-type-confusion)

As a final note: function SIGNATURES/DEFINITIONS are a great way to quickly look and understand what a snippet of code SHOULD do, but only the IMPLEMENTATION will show what it ACTUALLY does.

Answer (score 1):

You have not defined the function, but you have given a type signature. Hence, the compiler is telling you that you have not defined the function.

If you read the error, it tells you this explicitly, if you know that 'binding' means 'definition':

> The type signature for `‘repliNow’` lacks an accompanying binding.

This is essentially the compiler asking "Ok, `repliNow` is this type, but what is it actually?" A bit like if someone said "`a` is a number," you'd be inclined to ask "Ok, but what value does it have?"

Define the function, and this error will go away. This is something of the form:

```
repliNow int str = -- your implementation here.
```